# Api-platform order for children

Tags: sorting, children, api-platform.com

I just begin to use api-platform to GET some entities and all their children.
There is a self-join here, SQL looks like

```
entity e0_
        LEFT JOIN
    entity e1_ ON e0_.id = e1_.parent_id
```

I found the result records are sorted by id `ORDER BY e0_.id ASC`, while their children are not sorted.

My question is how to sort their children also `ORDER BY e0_.id ASC, e1_.id ASC`

I viewed the document, seems not mentioned.
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/default-order

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default order in ORM:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

Default order in API platform:

```
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"order"={"related.id": "ASC"}})
```

Order by query param in API platform:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#filtering-on-nested-properties

Comment: Thanks a lot!   it works! By the way, another case is that children only exist when a parameter like group=hierarchy, if group=read, no children.  Is there any way that I can define in api platform yaml file like if group=hierarchy, then order: ['id']; if group=read, then order: ['id', 'related.id'] ?

Answer (score 0):

GonZOOs answer didn't work in my case, couldn't figure out why, so I did it the ORM-way. I just put it in the annoutations of the one2many relation [Doctrine docu](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/tutorials/ordered-associations.html)
Remember that it is hardcoded then.